# IntelliJ Idea Ultimate cannot enter debugging mode

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to debug it shows this dialog:

[Error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnnvp.png)

And when I clock "fix" It shows this:

[Web Browsers dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6plGq.png)

I can't solve this problem, any suggestion? Also I am developing a react native app. But i don't think that's the problem...

I am running Intellij Idea in Elementary OS.

Comment: did you enable Chrome in the dialog?

Comment: Is chrome installed in your case? What does the run configuration look like? If you want to use Firefox (which is not recommended) you should use  Firefox Remote run configuration.

Comment: thanks for the comments, that was the problem, I didn't have chrome installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected - debugging is only supported in Chrome and browsers of the Chrome family, as it's clearly stated in [Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/configuring-javascript-debugger.html). So, when you start the debugger, the IDE will try to open Chrome regardless of the browser chosen in run configuration. You need to make sure that Chrome is installed and the correct path to it is specified in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**.

We used to support Firefox Remote Debugging (but without source maps) through the **FireFox Remote** run configuration, but our solution doesn't work in the latest Firefox versions due to changes in the protocol, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to fix it. We've made some progress recently, but there are still some blocking issues
related ticket: [WEB-45986](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45986)

Comment: That was the problem, I didn't have google chrome installed. Too bad it can't be used with firefox...